# How to get the ID of a given voice channel? - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have the following line of code, it is meant to take in a channel and give the id of it.

```
channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.channels, name='general', type="ChannelType.voice")
print(channel)
```

It ends up returning `None`, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_x` and `utils.get` both return `None` if they can't find anything matching.
Common causes include:

- Not subscribed to relevant intent
- Wrong key
- Bot not logged in, and trying to grab objects from cache
- Bot cannot "see" the object

You can try:

```py
channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.voice_channels, name='general')
```